# How to load a picture from private files into a layout (Android)?

Tags: android, file, layout

I have a picture saved in `/data/data/my.package.name/files/mypicture.png` and I would like to load it in a layout.

I tried this, but it does not work.

```
File filePath = getFileStreamPath("pictureIWouldLikeToLoad.png");
ImageView img = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
img.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(filePath.toString()));
ViewGroup picturesLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_pictures_area);
picturesLayout.addView(imgView);
```

I can not find out how it does not work, could someone explain me why ? And so how to what I want to do ? Do I need a Content Provider ? Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I succeeded. Maybe it could be improved, but here is something that actually works :

```
FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput("my_image.png");
BufferedInputStream bufferedInput = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);                       
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufferedInput);
ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_imageview);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
bufferedInput.close();
inputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

you should define an ID in your XML to the image you want to change

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/awesome_image"
.
.
.
/>
```

then you should convert the Image file into a Bitmap object

```
File file = new File("/data/data/my.package.name/files/mypicture.png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file);
```

finally you get the imageView object and sets its bitmap

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.awesome_image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: By the way, you can directly give the path to the `decodeFile` method like this : `Bitmap bmp =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/data/my.package.name/files/mypicture.png");`.